# how to prove $\mathbb{E}[UV\mid \mathcal{B} ] = U\mathbb{E}[V\mid \mathcal{B} ]$ if $U$ is $\mathcal{B}$-measurable?

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-expectation

How can we prove
$$\mathbb{E}[UV\mid \mathcal{B} ] = U\mathbb{E}[V\mid \mathcal{B} ]$$

given that both r.v's are positive and $U$ being $\mathcal{B}$-measurable?

I use this property pretty often but I don't know how to actually prove it. Either we have to show that $\forall B \in \mathcal{B}$

$$\int_{B}UVd\mathbb{P} =\int_{B}U\mathbb{E}[V \mid \mathcal{B} ] d\mathbb{P} $$

or $\forall Z \text{ that is }  \mathcal{B}$-measurable and positive

$$\mathbb{E}[UVZ] = \mathbb{E}[U\mathbb{E}[V\mid \mathcal{B} ]Z ]$$

but how?

Comment: Please replace every $\backslash$ by `\mid `.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that there exists a monotone sequence of simple random variables $U_n$ which are $\mathcal B$ - measurable converging point wise to $U$. The random variables $U_n$ can be written as
$$U_n=\sum_{k=1}^{N_n}\mathbf{1}_{A_{k,n}}$$
where $A_{k, n}\in\mathcal B $.

Now we have using MCT
\begin{align} 
\int_B UV\, d\mathbb P&=\int_{  B}\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{k=1}^{N_n}\mathbf{1}_{A_{k, n}} V\, d\mathbb P \\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{k=1}^{N_n}\int_{A_{k, n} \cap B} V\, d\mathbb P \\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{k=1}^{N_n}\int_{A_{k, n} \cap B} \mathbb E(V\mid \mathcal B)\, d\mathbb P\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{k=1}^{N_n}\int_{ B} \mathbf{1}_{A_{k,n}} \mathbb E(V\mid \mathcal B)\, d\mathbb P
\end{align} 
And this implies indeed using MCT again that...

You need to figure out how to use MCT yourself though.